# Spartacus Configurable Product Integration: Use custom Form Elements

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am currently experiencing issues with the Configurable Product Integration of Spartacus. So far I have set up the storefront to show my configurable products, which is working quite well.

Now I am trying to customize a form element, let's say an input field to insert a custom suffix that is dynamically added by the backend. Specifically, I am trying to replace the `cx-configurator-attribute-input-field`inside https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/feature-libs/product-configurator/rulebased/components/form/configurator-form.component.html

So far I have tried to import it in the module:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
            cmsComponents: {
                ConfiguratorAttributeInputField: {
                    component:CustomConfiguratorComponent
                }
            }
        })
```

which is not working, probably because the component is not a static CmsComponent.

I also tried importing it via outlet definition in typescript:

```
export class CustomConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private outletService: OutletService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomInputFieldComponent);
    this.outletService.add('cx-configurator-attribute-input-field', factory);
    console.log("REGISTERED");
  }

}
```

which is also not working.

When I add the outlet via ng-template to a template reference, I can see the component, so the import of the component should be working correctly:

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="VariantConfigurationTemplate" cxOutletPos="before">
    <app-custom-input-field></app-custom-input-field>
</ng-template>
```

How can I get this to work, so that I can replace a dynamically added Spartacus component? Specifically the ConfiguratorAttributeInputFieldComponent (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/feature-libs/product-configurator/rulebased/components/attribute/types/input-field/configurator-attribute-input-field.component.ts)

Comment: I got it working by replacing the whole ConfiguratorFormComponent, copy-pasting the html markup from the spartacus project, import the respective modules, and augment the html where needed with my custom components. So it works, but does not seem so seamless, and quite hacky tbh.

Comment: At the moment this is the best way. An initiative is in progress to offer a new mechanism that would make such a change easier and more seamless.

Comment: Aight, thanks for the response :) Keep up the good work!